# How can I prevent RecyclerView and GridView items from being resized in my application

Tags: android

I use recyclerView and GridView in my game

And when the user of your phone settings

Setting -> Display -> Display size changed to Large or small

The recyclerView and GridView items get bigger and smaller this causes the view to be cluttered

**The point is that I have defined the size of the items as large and standard and there is no need to change it because my app is an app game**

I searched for this problem but did not find a suitable and principled solution

Is there no suitable solution to this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you change the text size.
If I'm right only you need to set your text size as `dp`, not `sp`.

Comment: Text size is dp but in the user phone settings section, there are two things, one is to enlarge the text size and two screen zoom

Answer (score 0):

Use **px** instead of **dp** or **sp**.

### Bafore scaling:

[image: before image]

### After scaling:

[image: after image]